# Conflicts between useEffect in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have to create component which fetch data with pagination and filters. 
Filters are passed by props and if they changed, component should reset data and fetch it from page 0.

I have this:

```
const PaginationComponent = ({minPrice, maxPrice}) => {

  const[page, setPage] = useState(null);
  const[items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const fetchMore = useCallback(() => {
    setPage(prevState => prevState + 1);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (page === null) {
      setPage(0);
      setItems([]);
    } else {
      get(page, minPrice, maxPrice)
        .then(response => setItems(response));
    }
  }, [page, minPrice, maxPrice]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(null);
  },[minPrice, maxPrice]);
};
```

.. and there is a problem, because first useEffect depends on props, because I use them to filtering data and in second one I want to reset component. And as a result after changing props both useEffects run.

I don't have more ideas how to do it correctly.

Comment: I am not sure if we need 2nd useEffect. Children is re-rendered when props is changed.

Comment: Why do you `setPage(null)` when `minPrice` and `maxPrice` change and then you do a fetch request in another `useEffect` hook when these same props change?

Comment: I have to setPage for null, because what if somebody changes filters on page 0 ? :) 0 is equal to 0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the key here is to move `page` state up to the parent component and change the page to 0 whenever you change your filters. You can do it either with `useState`, or with `useReducer`.

The reason why it works with `useState` (i.e. there's only one rerender) is because React batches state changes in event handlers, if it didn't, you'd still end up with two API calls. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-dewdney-uzrxg)

```
const PaginationComponent = ({ page, minPrice, maxPrice, setPage }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    get(page, minPrice, maxPrice).then(response => setItems(response));
  }, [page, minPrice, maxPrice]);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          {item.id}, {item.name}, ${item.price}
        </div>
      ))}
      <div>Page: {page}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(v => v - 1)}>back</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(v => v + 1)}>next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [minPrice, setMinPrice] = useState(25);
  const [maxPrice, setMaxPrice] = useState(50);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Min price:</label>
        <input
          value={minPrice}
          onChange={event => {
            const { value } = event.target;
            setMinPrice(parseInt(value, 10));
            setPage(0);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Max price:</label>
        <input
          value={maxPrice}
          onChange={event => {
            const { value } = event.target;
            setMaxPrice(parseInt(value, 10));
            setPage(0);
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <PaginationComponent minPrice={minPrice} maxPrice={maxPrice} page={page} setPage={setPage} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

---

The other solution is to use `useReducer`, which is more transparent, but also, as usual with reducers, a bit heavy on the boilerplate. This example behaves a bit differently, because there is a "set filters" button that makes the change to the state that is passed to the pagination component, a bit more "real life" scenario IMO. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-glade-bmw6j)

```
const PaginationComponent = ({ tableConfig, setPage }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { page, minPrice, maxPrice } = tableConfig;
    get(page, minPrice, maxPrice).then(response => setItems(response));
  }, [tableConfig]);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          {item.id}, {item.name}, ${item.price}
        </div>
      ))}
      <div>Page: {tableConfig.page}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(v => v - 1)}>back</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(v => v + 1)}>next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const tableStateReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "setPage") {
    return { ...state, page: action.page };
  }
  if (action.type === "setFilters") {
    return { page: 0, minPrice: action.minPrice, maxPrice: action.maxPrice };
  }
  return state;
};

const App = () => {
  const [tableState, dispatch] = useReducer(tableStateReducer, {
    page: 0,
    minPrice: 25,
    maxPrice: 50
  });
  const [minPrice, setMinPrice] = useState(25);
  const [maxPrice, setMaxPrice] = useState(50);

  const setPage = useCallback(
    page => {
      if (typeof page === "function") {
        dispatch({ type: "setPage", page: page(tableState.page) });
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: "setPage", page });
      }
    },
    [tableState]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Min price:</label>
        <input
          value={minPrice}
          onChange={event => {
            const { value } = event.target;
            setMinPrice(parseInt(value, 10));
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Max price:</label>
        <input
          value={maxPrice}
          onChange={event => {
            const { value } = event.target;
            setMaxPrice(parseInt(value, 10));
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch({ type: "setFilters", minPrice, maxPrice });
        }}
      >
        Set filters
      </button>

      <PaginationComponent tableConfig={tableState} setPage={setPage} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following

```
const fetchData = () => {
 get(page, minPrice, maxPrice)
    .then(response => setItems(response));
}
// Whenever page updated fetch new data
useEffect(() => {
 fetchData();
}, [page]);

// Whenever filter updated reseting page
useEffect(() => {
 const prevPage = page;
 setPage(0);
 if(prevPage === 0 ) {
   fetchData();
 }
},[minPrice, maxPrice]);
```

Comment: But first effect depends on minPrice and maxPrice too. So it should listen on it.

Comment: As per your question, when filters change you only need to reset page, 2nd effect changes page. Then first effect will execute(because page changed), then get function will execute for getting the response. The value of minPrice and maxPrice will still be passed to `get` function

Comment: Ok so linter warning isn't important in this case ? But as I wrote above - I can't setPage for 0 ..

Comment: It can't set page for 0, because what if I am currently of page 0 in my pagination ? There is no difference so useEffect won't run.

Comment: I have updated the post, this might solve your problem